# ERROR ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, healthkit

I tried to upload my application to App Store Connect.
This app writes data to the Health app, but never reads them.
Therefore, I just added the key NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription in the Info.plist file.
However, when uploading the file, I get the following error :

ERROR ITMS-90683: "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist. Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSHealthShareUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more

My question: do I really have to include NSHealthShareUsageDescription if I don’t need to read the data from HealthKit?

I’m really confused. I certainly missed something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your answer is in the question: "While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required." so yes you need to add a purpose string

Comment: Thanks @JeromeDiaz. It is indeed written in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Jerome Diaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2119709/jerome-diaz) I indeed missed the sentence :  *While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required.*

It means that you **have to add** both strings:

- NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription
- NSHealthShareUsageDescription